# Does power of GPU affect performance of analyses by ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, performance

Does the power of GPU affect the performance of analyses such as Segment Mean Shift, conversion to/from raster, etc?

Is the GPU used only for caching GUI elements to give a smoother user interface or is it used for processing as well?

Comment: The only discourse I can remember about Esri and GPU performance was 3d rendering in ArcScene (or was it ArcGlobe). It is possible that rendering to caches during the refresh phase could involve graphic operations; I keep an eye on performance from task manager and resource monitor but don't know of a tool to log GPU load. Still, this is a bit too broad for GIS.SE unless someone has a white paper on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to be 3 Spatial Analyst tools in ArcGIS Pro AND ArcMap 10.5+ which can use the GPU to take the load of processing.

These are:

1. Aspect
2. Slope
3. Viewshed 2

ArcMap Link:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/gpu-processing-with-spatial-analyst.htm

ArcGIS Pro Link:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/gpu-processing-with-spatial-analyst.htm

Pro does make use of parallel processing, which can assist in sharing the load of running tools. I cannot find examples of ArcMap using this function from my limited research.

From the link below, I found that Segment Mean Shift supports Parallel Processing.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/parallel-processing-with-spatial-analyst.htm

Setting Parallel Processing Factors:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/parallel-processing-factor.htm